# Getting wrong date when using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting a date time from an api `2022-04-01T00:00:00.000Z`,
and I am using moment to get day and date from the api response in following way:

`console.log(moment(resp.data.shift_date).format('ddd, MMM Do, YYYY'));`

OUTPUT: `Thu, Mar 31st, 2022`.
But the date which I am getting from api is of 1st april, 2022. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Date time from API is UTC but your output will be local time equivalent.

Comment: The date is being localised to your timezone.

Comment: @phuzi how can I avoid this

Comment: Use `moment.utc(resp.data.shift_date)` instead of `moment(resp.data.shift_date)`. It's all in [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Answer (score 0):

try `moment.utc(dt).format('ddd, MMM Do, YYYY')`

dt is your date coming from API.